# How to Upgrade version pipelinedb

Tags: pipelinedb

Upgrade version pipelinedb

What the last version of the extension kafka for pipelinedb ?

How to download the last version.

I use version 0.9.3

Answer (score 0):

The pipeline_kafka extension is not coupled to PipelineDB releases by version. It is a separate extension and is updated regularly, independently of PipelineDB releases.

You can download [pipeline_kafka](https://github.com/pipelinedb/pipeline_kafka) and the latest edition of [PipelineDB](https://www.pipelinedb.com/download) for the latest versions of both.